# How do I make a Post to server in Swift 2?

Tags: xcode, swift, post, swift2, xcode7

How do I make this code comparable with swift 2. I want to make a request post to the server. I am receiving many errors and deprecated code when I switched to swift 2.

//Authentication code
        var username:NSString = emailTextField.text!
        var password:NSString = passwordTextField.text!

```
    if ( username.isEqualToString("") || password.isEqualToString("") )
    {


        var alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
        alertView.title = "Sign in Failed!"
        alertView.message = "Please enter Username and Password"
        alertView.delegate = self
        alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
        alertView.show()
    } else {


        //var post:NSString = "username=\(username)&password=\(password)"

        var post:NSString = "tag=login&email=\(username)&password=\(password)"



        NSLog("PostData: %@",post);

        //var url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://localhost/phploginws/index.php")!

        var url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://192.168.1.14:8080/phploginws/index.php")!

        var postData:NSData = post.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!

        var postLength:NSString = String( postData.length )

        var request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.HTTPBody = postData
        request.setValue(postLength as String, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")


        var reponseError: NSError?
        var response: NSURLResponse?

        var urlData: NSData? = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response, error:&reponseError)

        if ( urlData != nil ) {
            let res = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse!;

            NSLog("Response code: %ld", res.statusCode);

            if (res.statusCode >= 200 && res.statusCode < 300)
            {
                var responseData:NSString  = NSString(data:urlData!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

                NSLog("Response ==> %@", responseData);

                var error: NSError?

                let jsonData:NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers , error: &error) as! NSDictionary


                let success:NSInteger = jsonData.valueForKey("success") as! NSInteger

                //[jsonData[@"success"] integerValue];

                NSLog("Success: %ld", success);

                if(success == 1)
                {
                    NSLog("Login SUCCESS");

                    var prefs:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
                    prefs.setObject(username, forKey: "USERNAME")
                    prefs.setInteger(1, forKey: "ISLOGGEDIN")
                    prefs.synchronize()

                    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                } else {
                    var error_msg:NSString

                    if jsonData["error_message"] as? NSString != nil {
                        error_msg = jsonData["error_message"] as! NSString
                    } else {
                        error_msg = "Unknown Error"
                    }
                    var alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
                    alertView.title = "Sign in Failed!"
                    alertView.message = error_msg as String
                    alertView.delegate = self
                    alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
                    alertView.show()

                }

            } else {
                var alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
                alertView.title = "Sign in Failed!"
                alertView.message = "Connection Failed"
                alertView.delegate = self
                alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
                alertView.show()
            }
        } else {
            var alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
            alertView.title = "Sign in Failed!"
            alertView.message = "Connection Failure"
            if let error = reponseError {
                alertView.message = (error.localizedDescription)
            }
            alertView.delegate = self
            alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
            alertView.show()
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you have a specific error you can't resolve, you are welcome to post it here. However, dumping a bunch of code and asking to translate it to Swift 2 is not ok.

Answer (score 0):

There should be an option in Xcode 7 to convert to the newest Swift syntax (Swift 2). If there are any errors or things not working, this should resolve your problems.

Can be found under:

> Edit > Convert > To Swift 2.0 / To Latest Swift Syntax